# Django API list with pagination - Page is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, pagination, serialization

I am trying to create a Django API for a list with pagination but have this error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Page' is not JSON serializable
```

The following is my API code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def employee_get_list_by_page(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: employee_get_list_by_page
    parameters:
      - name: token
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form       
      - name: page
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form   
      - name: page_limit
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form                   
    """
    token = request.POST['token']
    try:  
        auth_employee = AuthEmployeeSessionToken.objects.get(token=token) 

    except AuthEmployeeSessionToken.DoesNotExist:   
        return Response("Invalid Token", status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

    employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(company = auth_employee.employee.company.id) 


    page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
    paginator = Paginator(employee_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

    try:
        employees = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        employees = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
    except EmptyPage:
        employees = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return Response(employees,status=status.HTTP_200_OK) <-- passing employees probably cause this error that employees as Page is not JSON serializable.
```

This is my model https://gist.github.com/axilaris/89b2ac6a7762f428ad715f4916f43967. as_dict notice I have this .as_dict() to create my json for response. I use it for single request but for list Im not sure how it is done.

1. How do an API query for this list with pagination support ?
2. Side issue which I want the JSON to list just the fields that I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had a go at recreating this, and I see a few ways to fix it.

Firstly, JSON will not be able to parse either the Page object, nor the QuerySet underlying the `page.object_list` property.  It will say `"Object of type 'Employee' is not JSON serialisable"`.

So to solve this, I'd try:

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(company = auth_employee.employee.company.id).values().order_by('id') 

page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
paginator = Paginator(employee_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

try:
    employees = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    employees = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
except EmptyPage:
    employees = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return Response(list(employees) ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Firstly, we use `.values()` on the employees queryset because the resulting ValuesQuerySet of this call can be parsed with `list(employees)`.  Inside the Page class, they evaluate the object list inside the instance this way before returning any results.

Lastly, because JSON can't serialise the Page class, we simply call `list(Page)` to return a list.  This works because Page implements `__getitem__` and returns the underlying object_list.

Also, you may find that some datatypes will throw JSON serialization errors (`values()` will return DateTime objects for DateTime fields).  In my testing I had an issue with `Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable`.  If this happens, you need to use a different JSON Encoder or extend your own.  The DjangoJSONEncoder can be found in django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder and handles datetimes, uuids, decimals, and other common datatypes in django.

Edit:: You've mentioned your model code as:

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def as_dict(self):

        return {"id": "%d" % self.id,
                "company": self.company.as_dict(),
                "username": self.username if self.username else "",
                "email": self.email if self.email else "",
                "first_name": self.first_name if self.first_name else "",
                "last_name": self.last_name if self.last_name else "",
                "tel":self.tel if self.tel else "",               
                "created_at":self.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                "updated_at":self.updated_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}
```

Because you have this `as_dict` method, we could use this to render the representation of your employees instead of relying on `.values()`.  Here is how:

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(company = auth_employee.employee.company.id).order_by('id') 

page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
paginator = Paginator(employee_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

try:
    employees = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    employees = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
except EmptyPage:
    employees = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
#  Here we map a lambda function over the queryset of Models to return the dictionary representation for each element in the list
employees_page = list(
    map(lambda employee: employee.as_dict(), list(employees))
)
return Response(employees_page ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Im not able to get pass the query. here is the error https://gist.github.com/axilaris/226ad1e0dde14d96b1be6eb71ddd6e88

Comment: i added one more reference https://gist.github.com/axilaris/89b2ac6a7762f428ad715f4916f43967 on how i design my model to also display json fields that I want. Anything that can be used from there ?

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer to fix that issue with the ordering.  Based on your models I will extend my answer a little to help you.

Comment: Thanks! it works. Can I ask whether can get answer for the no.2, say in the list i only want to have id, username only. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Axil I've added to my answer to use your models `as_dict` method so it will display as you wish.

Comment: tqvm but somehow there is syntax error passing employee_page 
 to Response. Can check the trackback error here: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/c0600cb205e690f5ebc8ceb5027f8acd

Comment: You are correct, I've fixed that error.  I missed a parentheses on the map call.  Should work now :)

Comment: there is still a problem with lambda calling as_dict() https://gist.github.com/axilaris/ee40b0936d7d5591275d593acdcdd62a. Here is how I use as_dict() to work, https://gist.github.com/axilaris/36b678158f9d751d1544d01ccbb75074

Comment: fyi - the result if we dont use lambda its like this. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a92f7be8978212a9cbabbf10b9d120ea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160559/discussion-between-axil-and-arjmp).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using Django Rest Framework (DRF) finds this, [DRF serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) can serialize `page.object_list` to JSON. Of course, the better way is to specify `pagination_class` in DRF view(set)s: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/