# Django Rest API, return json list of a model with only required fields - lambda did not work

Tags: python, json, django, list, lambda

In my Django Rest API, I have problem trying to do a query list and return json response based on the fields that I require (like just id, username instead of all in the model). One way is trying with lambda but it didnt work.

This is a continuation for this: [Django API list with pagination - Page is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664945/django-api-list-with-pagination-page-is-not-json-serializable)

I have an API query where I want to list model record of specific fields. For example (just id and username) instead of all the fields in the model. I am trying to use lambda to generate the json fields according to a helper function .as_dict() defined in the model. But it causes an error as show in the traceback below.

Here is my function based rest API, see the lambda part at the bottom that is the problem:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def employee_get_list_by_page(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: employee_get_list_by_page
    parameters:
      - name: token
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form       
      - name: page
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form   
      - name: page_limit
        type: string
        required: true
        location: form                   
    """
    token = request.POST['token']
    try:  
        auth_employee = AuthEmployeeSessionToken.objects.get(token=token) 

    except AuthEmployeeSessionToken.DoesNotExist:   
        return Response("Invalid Token", status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)


    employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(company = auth_employee.employee.company.id).order_by('id') 

    page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
    paginator = Paginator(employee_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

    try:
       employees = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
       employees = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
    except EmptyPage:
       employees = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    #  Here we map a lambda function over the queryset of Models to return the dictionary representation for each element in the list
    employees_page = list(
       map(lambda employee: employee.as_dict(), list(employees))
    )
    return Response(employees_page ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is the error from the traceback:
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/ee40b0936d7d5591275d593acdcdd62a

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'as_dict'
```

without the lambda, the result it returns the result that looks like this. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a92f7be8978212a9cbabbf10b9d120ea. Maybe it doesnt recognize .as_dict() because of employee key does not exist ? I am not familiar how lambda works here.

model.py (Employee model with as_dict() for json)

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def as_dict(self):
        return {"id": "%d" % self.id,
                "username": self.username if self.username else ""}
```

Question:
How can do I query list and return a json response based on the fields that I require (like just id, username instead of all) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(company = auth_employee.employee.company.id).values("id", "username").order_by('id')
```

Comment: its still the same problem: 'dict' object has no attribute 'as_dict'

Comment: if i run it without lambda it works. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a27b0519f6df5eff148cd4feb2473ff4. Any ideas how to use as_dict() ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: it can still output but not using as_dict() output but all of the model fields. Here is the code based your answer https://gist.github.com/axilaris/5ee2757ee0a3233123453c3de33d6311

Comment: the above code will return TypeError: Object of type 'Page' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Instead of trying all this, have you tried values in filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160563/discussion-between-axil-and-rajkris).